# Rails error: Couldn't find database client: sqlite3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, console

I'm using Rails in a development environment. I'm trying to run simple INSERT commands via the command line, but I can't seem to connect to the SQLite database. Other database-related commands are working fine (e.g. `rake db:migrate`). I'm using the following command:

```
rails dbconsole
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
Couldn't find database client: sqlite3. Check your $PATH and try again.
```

I'm still learning Rails and I'm hoping you rails Rails experts out there will be able to spot the issue.

Comment: Is `rails console` working fine ?

Comment: Yep, `rails console` is working.

Comment: Do you have sqlite3 installed on the computer? To test this you should be able to just go to your command line and type sqlite3 and it should load you into the sqlite> prompt

Comment: It looks like you do not have the `sqlite3` command installed ? could you give use your operating system details ?

Comment: Ha, how silly of me. You're right, I didn't have sqlite3 installed. Installed it and worked. Thanks!

Comment: Is this Q&A too trivial? Should I delete it or would someone like to post an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sqlite3 isn't installed on your computer, go to the [sqlite site](http://www.sqlite.org/) and install the command line utility according to whichever operating system your using.